# How do I retrieve the response.URL using Faraday gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, net-http, faraday

I'm using **Faraday** to check for broken links, and I want to retrieve the **response.URL** of the links I'm querying, however, I am not able to find any documentation and examples to do so.

I was able to do this on the front-end using Javascript's Fetch API (Response.url: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/url) but that is not an option now as I am required to do this on the backend using Faraday only.

Is this even possible with Faraday? If so, how do I implement it? Or kindly point me to the right documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of class variables instantiated in the response object: `response.env`
You might be looking at:

```
response.env.url.to_s
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I need. Though, may I ask, how do I output all the variables/attributes of response.env? Say, I want to check what other variables are there other than response.env.url. I haven't found any guide to do it in the official docs.

Comment: Great! In order to debug. you can use inspect to see the content of a class. "puts response.inspect" or "puts response.env.inspect"

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!